# Install Neo4j via Maven

Tags: solaris, nosql, maven, smartos

Neo4j says I can install Neo4j via Maven by adding it to my build:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But do I need a build?
If so, what should my `pom.xml` look like?

I tried with this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.webcom.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>webcom</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>webcom</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.M04</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But then I end up with:

```
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] /opt/local/java/sun6/../lib/tools.jar
```

I have installed `sun-jdk6-6.0.26` and set `JAVA_HOME` to `/opt/local/java/sun6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved as follows:

1. Go to directory: /opt/local/java
2. Execute "sudo ln -s sun6/lib/"
3. To verify execute "sudo ls -ld lib"

Now your Maven command will run without problem.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The env var `$JAVA_HOME` should point to the directory containing `bin`, so that `$JAVA_HOME/bin` contains `javac`. (You probably worked-around a mis-configured env var that might cause other problems later -- e.g., not finding other parts of the JDK)

Verify that everything is set up correctly by running: `type javac` (and `type java`) , `javac -version` (and `java -version`). If the wrong version is found, check the path & java_home (always: `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`)

If using eclipse (a common misconfiguration issue), you'll have to configure your jdk via the preferences -> installed jre's (or possibly project->java build path->libraries->JRE System Library->edit->"workspace default JRE")